# Lua get Max number

Tags: lua, love2d

I am facing an issue getting max number of attributes of an Array

```
-- Getting Maximum number of full grids inside Row
maxRow = math.max(checkerRow[1],checkerRow[2],checkerRow[3],checkerRow[4],checkerRow[5],
                    checkerRow[6],checkerRow[7],checkerRow[8],checkerRow[9],checkerRow[10],
                    checkerRow[11],checkerRow[12],checkerRow[13],checkerRow[14],checkerRow[15],
                    checkerRow[16],checkerRow[17],checkerRow[18],checkerRow[19],checkerRow[20])

print("Max Row : "..maxRow)
```

so it prints out the value inside maxRow, I need something that can actually give me the number of the Row, like if checkerRow[6] is the max number, then I need the maxRow to be equal to 6.

*I am sorry if you find this question for stupid, I am new into Lua.*

Answer (score 5):

This is simple implementation. You may wrap it in function.

```
local mi, mv = 1, checkerRow[1]
for i = 2, 20 do
    if checkerRow[i] > mv then
        mi, mv = i, checkerRow[i]
    end
end
```

Comment: What is this ? I don't understand it at all

Comment: math.max does not return position. so you need write your own implementation. mi = max index, mv = max value.